# Virtual enviroment in D drive

Tags: python, environment

I am wondering if we able to create a virtual enviroment in drive D. I use windows 10 and python is installed in C drive but I want to create virtual enviroment in drive D.

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: A "virtual enviroment" is what?

Comment: The question is tagged with python, I think the question is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a python virtual environment everywhere.

```bash
python -m venv <pathtoyourvenv>
```